# Dell 3800 vostro unable to play sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, dell-vostro

I am unable to hear any sound on my dell vostro 3800. It has Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I can type whatever command you want me type and give you the information.

Answer (score 0):

## If this is your first time using ubuntu

Try installing codecs

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

OR install ubuntu-restricted-extras from ubuntu software center

## If this doesn't work

Try typing this in terminal

```
alsamixer
```

press f6 to select your sound card.

In this application,
make sure to set all channels to high volume levels. Make sure the different speakers (especially 'Front', 'Master', and 'PCM") are NOT muted and NOT set to low volume levels in alsamixer. Move with the left and right keys on your keyboard until the "Master" item is highlighted (in red). If the letters "MM" are displayed under the volume bar, press "M" to unmute. Repeat with the "Master Mono", "Headphone", "PCM", "Front", "Surround", "Center" and "LFE" items. Press Esc when finished.

Comment: still does not work. I am not getting any sound after doing both. Should I reboot ?

Comment: @user311554 Try doing this after opening the **alsamixer**      make sure to set all channels to high volume levels.

Comment: I ran those commands you asked me to. I opened alsamixer and how do I know what my sound card is ?

Comment: select default. and i edited the answer.do check

Comment: Does not work. Sorry.

Comment: Try this **killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ~/.config/pulse** and wait for few seconds. and run **pulseaudio -k** reboot the system.

Comment: If this fails read this [link](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18366/discussion-between-ansuman-and-user311554).

Comment: after following your instructions my sound settings disappeared. Please do not copy and paste answers till you have tried them yourself. I am not blaming you but I hope nothing is wrong with my Ubuntu.

Comment: i am sorry for the trouble.But I was just trying to help since I too had this problem.